# how can i implement the singleton class in swift which will be having uiview as base class

Tags: swift, singleton

I am trying to create a singleton class that having base class as `uiview` but I am getting this error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SecondView' with no arguments

```
import UIKit
class SecondView: BaseView {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

static let secondViewSharedInstance = SecondView()
//MARK: - Custom Initialization
internal init(frame: CGRect, OnActions:(ScreeenType:NSInteger) -> ()){

    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

}
```

How can I fix this issue? It is working fine when I have taken new project and copied this code but in my main project I am getting the above error

I have taken a base view

```
import UIKit
class BaseView: UIView {
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

var OnActionsRef : (ScreeenType:NSInteger) -> () = {_ in };
}
```

Comment: The code works for me, at what point does that error appear?

Comment: I am getting the compile time error.. I am Using Xcode 7.2

Comment: yes but where does it occur in your code? There's certainly no problem with the code you wrote. If you can give some more information it would help people answer your question.

Comment: please help me in this i have updated the question